# Webpack entry point per component

Tags: angular, webpack, code-splitting

I am creating Angular application, which for my use case, does not require routing, and the output of the build process needs to be broken down per component or per module.

Angular compiles into main, vendor, polyfills etc. The main.bundle.js is has all of my modules/components/directives/services etc inside. I need the output instead to be something like: component1.bundle.js, component2.bundle.js; instead of one main.bundle.js file.

How do I approach this with regards to webpack and the entry points? Does it have to be the main.ts in order for the outputted files to function? I can do something like:

```
  entry: {
    'main': 'src/main.ts',
    'component1': 'src/app/components/component1.ts
    'component2': 'src/app/components/component2.ts
```

And get an output. But I don't know if this is something that I should be investing time into if it needs to be the main.ts.

My use case:

The application will sit inside of a content management system (CMS). When a user builds a webpage in the CMS they select a content type, for example 'text with image' content type, and the functionality of that content type is defined by an Angular component/module, and the code is stored per content type in the CMS.

Comment: I’m wondering if you don’t just mean / need lazy loaded modules (or components?)

Comment: Good point. I looked at this and it seems like what I need, but I was confused when it came to the requirement to create routes as otherwise I don't need to think about routing in this case. Lazy loaded modules maybe something I need to look into further

Comment: how do you expect to use your components?

Comment: @dan - you don’t necessarily need routed paths in order to lazy load modules, you can also do this programmatically if needed..